What is vi command package?
I can't find the name of vi command package.
I didn't find it in dpkg -S and apt-file.
What is the /bin/vi command package?

It's most likely provided by one of the vim packages, using the update-alternatives mechanism:
$ ls -l /usr/bin/vi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 30 20:15 /usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi

$ update-alternatives --list vi
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/bin/vim.tiny

$ dpkg -S vim.basic
vim: /usr/bin/vim.basic


There is also nvi
